# Bundling Angular 2 for product with WebStorm 2016.3

Tags: angular, webstorm, angular2-build

I'm developing a small web application using Angular 2 with WebStorm.
I wonder how could I bundle my web application using WebStorm.

I saw my friend, he used Visual Code to bundle his Angular 2 project. After project has been minimized, the output is :

- 1 index file,
- 1 polyfill file
- 1 vendor file.

How can I achieve the same thing with WebStorm 2016.3 ?

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm doesn't have any built-in bundlers. You can use a bundler of your choice (Broccoli, Webpack, etc.). Webpack is officially recommended to be used with Angular2 - please see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

I would also suggest trying [angular cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli),  it will create a default configuration to start with.

See also https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/02/webinar-recording-using-webstorm-for-building-angular-apps/